# Incomplete type not allowed in C++

Tags: class, c++11, c++17

I am trying to recreate the data type of array for experimental purposes. I created a class "node" with two attributes value(int) and nextvalue(node) to hold the next node. The plan was to chain a number of node objects together and create an array. 
here is my code:

```
class node
{
public :int value;
        node nextnode;
};
```

However, I get the following error in the line `node nextnode;` : incomplete type not allowed 
Like it is some sort of "recursive class" if that even exists.

I have even tried creating a second class named "node2" that was the exact same with the previous one so as to trick the compiler int thinking the class didn't reference itself.
Is there a solution or is this a dead end?

Comment: with your design what do you think is `sizeof(node)`?

Comment: yes, you are right, it would be infinite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike other language (for instance C#) a class is always a value type, not a reference. So a class cannot have a member of the type of the same class (you would get infinite recursion and a class with infinite size). Also please note that in C++ class and struct are identical (except for the default access modifier)

So you need to use pointers:

```
#include <memory>

class node
{
public:
    int value;
    std::unique_ptr<node> nextnode;
};
```